# Rails Production server/console not reloading module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using DelayedJob for a long running task in my app. I have the job defined in a class MyJob saved in app/jobs/my_job.rb.

All was well, but I added some code to the file and restarted the server and the changes are not up. Before it was saving one field and now it should be saving two, and I added a logger.debug line to help me, but nothing is coming up in the logs and the models aren't being saved with the field.

This is in 'production' (though still using Thin webserver). 
development works.

Since the folder is in the autoload path (at least if I am not misunderstood) I didn't think I needed to do anything special. But since it is not working, something must be off. Help? Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Did you run `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart`? Delayed Job uses its own process(es), so you might also have to restart it.

Comment: I had thought that might be my problem, and did a RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop // start (I stopped it, stopped my server, and then started both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I had a worker who was off the radar.
I run my server in a docker container (should have mentioned that) so even though I did a

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart
```

in both the container and the host (the container has the app from the host as a volume), a worker I probably started some other time continued on. I saw it in the logs when I went back, so I did a

```
kill {pid}
```

and that solved my problem. So Flavio was right, I just had to kill the worker myself because the script wasn't picking it up.